# Soundcloud Widget API doesn't seem to listen to color option

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I was trying to create a soundcloud embed with a specific button color through the Widget API, which according to the Soundcloud documentation should work. However the color never gets added to the embed url, it only says 'color=true'.

After some digging in the source code, color could never work as this is the code that adds it to the url:

```
function g(n) {
  var t, e, r = [];
  for (t in n) n.hasOwnProperty(t) && (e = n[t], r.push(t + "=" + ("start_track" === t ? parseInt(e, 10) : e ? "true" : "false")));
  return r.join("&")
}
```

Is there a way to fix this? I can't directly add color to the url, because I'm using another package that checks for a plain soundcloud url.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work in the [Widget API Playground](https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html) by specifying the `color` URL query parameter on the track URL: `http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/90787841&color=0066CC`

Notice that the play button color is now blue, not the default orange:

[image: Widget]